# how to stop docker automatically launch jupyter notebooks

Tags: docker, jupyter

When I try to run a docker container as below:

```
docker run tensorflow/tensorflow:1.11.0-py3
```

It always launch jupyter notebook and shows messages as below:

```
[I 06:39:47.738 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 06:39:47.754 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
[I 06:39:47.754 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 06:39:47.754 NotebookApp] http://(9174ca4d537a or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=5a7031a41c376d89a08583ada6a7c4a8669b667967a5a90e
[I 06:39:47.754 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 06:39:47.754 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://(9174ca4d537a or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=5a7031a41c376d89a08583ada6a7c4a8669b667967a5a90e
```

But I don't want to launch jupyter noteook automatically. I've tried to remove jupyter but no lucks.
How do I stop jupyter running or how do I completely remove jupyter notebook?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/1.11.0-py3/images/sha256-7f147470ab6f94f52a1a1ef6211ce6ae645ed863f493b6cad16d428fbaed898b
```

You need to modify the image or try another tag of tensorflow/tensorflow that not uses jupyter notebooks. You can find here all the options of tags for tensorflow:

```
 https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags
```